# JS Как изменять значение в input=text после нажатие на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как изменять значение в input=text value после нажатие на кнопку button

То есть имеются несколько кнопок, button A button B button C и одно поле, после нажатие на кнопку, меняется значение в поле input type=text

Вот пример мой с radio работает, а с кнопкой button - как сделать?

```js
$('input.trip').on('change', function() {
    $('#my_field').val( $(this).val() );
});

$('input.but').on('change', function() {
    $('#my_field2').val( $(this).val() );
});

$('input.but').on('change', function() {
    $('#my_field3').val( $(this).val() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" class="trip" name="rad" value="a">A
<input type="radio" class="trip" name="rad" value="b">B
<input type="radio" class="trip" name="rad" value="c">C

<input type="text" id="my_field" value="">


<input type="submit" class="sub" value="a">
<input type="submit" class="sub" value="b">
<input type="submit" class="sub" value="c">

<input type="text" id="my_field2" value="">


<button class="but" class="but" value="a">A</button>
<button class="but" class="but" value="b">B</button>
<button class="but" class="but" value="c">C</button>

<input type="text" id="my_field3" value="">
```

Вот кнопки button и submit не работает
Или я что то не так делаю ?

Answer (score 3):

Так хотели?

```js
$('input.trip').on('change', function() {
    $('#my_field').val( $(this).val() );
});

$('input.sub').on('click', function() {
    $('#my_field2').val( $(this).val() );
});

$('button.but').on('click', function() {
    $('#my_field3').val( $(this).val() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" class="trip" name="rad" value="a">A
<input type="radio" class="trip" name="rad" value="b">B
<input type="radio" class="trip" name="rad" value="c">C

<input type="text" id="my_field" value="">


<input type="submit" class="sub" value="a">
<input type="submit" class="sub" value="b">
<input type="submit" class="sub" value="c">

<input type="text" id="my_field2" value="">


<button class="but" value="a">A</button>
<button class="but" value="b">B</button>
<button class="but" value="c">C</button>

<input type="text" id="my_field3" value="">
```